# How to center fragment dialog layout with two NumberPicker and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I'm playing around with the android app. There wasn't a problem to markup main Activity with ConstraintLayout and visual editor. But looks like it works different with DialogFragment. I have the following DialogFragment code

```
public class AmountPickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.amount_picker_dialog, null);
    NumberPicker amountPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.amountPicker);
    amountPicker.setMinValue(1);
    amountPicker.setMaxValue(100);

    NumberPicker amountPickerTotal = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.amountPickerTotal);
    amountPickerTotal.setMinValue(1);
    amountPickerTotal.setMaxValue(100);

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(view)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.amount_picker_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.amount_picker_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    AmountPickerFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

And here is my layout markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/amountPickerLaout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="of" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/amountPickerTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output is 
[image]

I want something like 
[image]

Please suggest how can I achieve such dialog layout.

Comment: Remove weight of textview and give gravity center to LinearLayout

Comment: @VipulPatel yep, this works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/amountPickerLaout"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="of"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/amountPickerTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/amountPickerLaout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="of" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/amountPickerTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have a look at this you can tweak it further very easily to align the view as you would like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/amountPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="of"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/amountPickerTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```